# realloc does not copy values correctly

Tags: c

I am trying to read a text file with unknown size into an array. I do that by reading one character at a time into the array and reallocate memory if the the end of the array is reached.

Starting from the increase in array size from 16 to 32, the realloc method copies only the first 4 characters.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


int main()
{
    int *text_arr = malloc(1*sizeof(int));
    text_arr[0] = '\0';
    int text_len=1;
    int i=0;
    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen("1.txt", "r");
    
    while ((text_arr[i] = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
        /* increment i for next loop */
        i++;

        /* extend the array if needed */
        if (i >= text_len) {
            /* debug prints */
            printf("Text: ");
            for (int n=0; n<i; n++)
                printf("%c,", text_arr[n]);
            printf("\n\n");
            
            /* double array size */
            text_len *= 2;
            text_arr = (int*)realloc(text_arr, text_len);
        }
    }
    text_arr[i] = '\0';

    fclose(fp);
    
    return 0;
}
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: `while ((text_arr[i] = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)` fgetc() returns an int. You fold it into a char before comparing, losing the EOF condition.

Comment: @wildplasser No, `text_arr[i]` is an `int` object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are working with `sizeof (int)` sized objects, you need to make sure to multiply your requested *number of bytes* by this size when you reallocate.

```
realloc(text_arr, sizeof (int) * text_len);
```

Answer (score 3):

[`realloc` takes the size **in bytes** as argument](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_realloc.htm). However, you are passing the size **in elements**, which will be lower by a factor of the size of `int` (usually 4) since you have `int`s as elements. That means that you are actually making the array *smaller* after the first resize, and then you keep writing beyond the end of the array.

Adding `* sizeof(int)` just like you have it in your `malloc` line should fix it:

```c
text_arr = (int*)realloc(text_arr, text_len * sizeof(int));
```

Answer (score 3):

Consider what happens the first time `text_len` is increased (from 1 to 2).  You had originally allocated `sizeof(int)` bytes to `text_arr`.  However, when you call `realloc(text_arr, text_len)` and `text_len` is 2, you're **truncating** the array from 4 bytes to 2 (assuming that `sizeof(int)` is 4).

`text_arr` shouldn't be an `int*` since you're reading individual characters into it and referencing them by `text_arr[n]`.  Instead, it should be a `char*` and allocated by `malloc(1*sizeof(char))` (or just `malloc(1)` since `sizeof(char)` is defined to be 1).

Also, with this change, you won't be able to store the return value of `fgetc` into the array when it's equal to `EOF`.  Therefore, you should store the return value into an actual `int` variable and then, if it's not `EOF`, store it into the array.